# What is the effect of setting the width of the html element and body element?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

So I ran into a problem where jQuery UI had some problems calculating positioning correctly in its sortable widget - only in IE. I was able to pinpoint the problem to the css applied to the html dom element:

```
html, body
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 968px;
}
```

Setting the width on the html element is what caused the particular problem. You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FUzJd/3/show/). In pretty much any version of IE, dragging an item doesn't push other items out of the way unless you move the item way to the right, about half the width of the left margin.

So anyway it got me wondering - what does setting the width of the html element do? And what does IE do different with respect to html width when it comes to positioning elements?

Comment: html is just the outermost tag - if you constrict the width of the html tag...then you will only be able to use that percentage of the width of the screen for the rest of whatever you do.

Comment: Instead of setting a width on the HTML/Body tags, you should set up a "container" div with the static width.

Comment: @APAD1 Agreed, that's how I've always done it. For the record I inherited this code :)

Answer (score 0):

The rendering engine used by IE is obviously more difficult to examine than an open source solution such as WebKit, but there *is* a discrepancy between how IE interprets the box model layout framework and the rest of the world.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Width attribute is even supported by html or body tag. html tag supports three attributes 'dir', 'lang' and 'version'. So this could have caused the problem that you are trying to set which does not exist for that tag.

Comment: Not as an attribute. But what about width via css on the html tag?